# Yii2 request post with name not working due to nested with _csrf array

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am wanting to use the following code within my controller which I think the code below is correct:

```
        $user = User::findOne(['username'=>$username]);
        $profile = UserProfile::findOne(['user_id' => $user->id]);

         if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post('User')) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post('UserProfile'))) {
```

However it doesn't work and goes straight to the else statement below however if I used the below it executes code within the if statement:

```
        if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post('_csrf')))
```

When using var_dump I get the following output which is below, as you can see the User info and UserProfile are nested within is this correct and if so how can I change the first line to work:

```
array(3) { ["_csrf"]=> string(56) "dsadasdasdasdas==" ["UserProfile"]=> array(3) { ["avatar"]=> string(0) "" ["social"]=> array(3) { ["facebook"]=> string(0) "" ["twitter"]=> string(0) "" ["instagram"]=> string(0) "" } ["bio"]=> string(5) "hello" } ["User"]=> array(3) { ["username"]=> string(22) "fsdfsdfsadminjkhnbnmbb" ["email"]=> string(23) "dasdasdh@yahoo.com" ["password"]=> string(14) "web16prounibar" } }
```

Full Controller Action

```
    public function actionProfile($username)
{

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && $username == Yii::$app->user->identity->username){

        $user = User::findOne(['username'=>$username]);
        $profile = UserProfile::findOne(['user_id' => $user->id]);

        // load user data with role and validate them
         if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            // only if user entered new password we want to hash and save it
            if ($user->password) 
            {
                $user->setPassword($user->password);
            }     

            $user->save(false);

            if ($profile->avatar){ 
                $imageName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '-' . $user->username;
                $profile->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($profile, 'avatar');
                $profile->filename = $imageName.'.'.$profile->file->extension;
                $profile->file->saveAs('uploads/avatars/'.$imageName.'.'.$profile->file->extension);
                $profile->avatar = '/uploads/avatars/'.$imageName.'.'.$profile->file->extension;
            }

            $profile->save(false);

            return $this->goHome();
        }else{

           return $this->render('update', [
                'user' => $user,
                'profile' => $profile,
            ]);
        }
    }else{
        return $this->goHome();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you've posted, the first *load* call has also the request for `UserProfile`. You missed the parentheses.

```
if ( $user->load(Yii::$app->request->post('User')) && $user->load(Yii::$app->request->post('UserProfile')) )
```

**UPDATE**

¿What field of the form has the file instance? loaded avatar attribute will always be empty because the file info goes in `$_FILES`, not in `$_POST`. So, the condition to update would be:

```
$profile->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($profile, 'avatar');

if ($profile->file != null) {
  $imageName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '-' . $user->username;

  $profile->file->saveAs('uploads/avatars/'.$imageName.'.'.$profile->file->extension);
  $profile->avatar = $imageName.'.'.$profile->file->extension;
  $profile->save(false);

}
```

You could also add a rule validation in your model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }
```

**Info**: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md

Comment: Apologies I obviously rushed to post the question I have now update the first code snippet which the correct code I am using which doesnt work

Comment: Don't worry. All queries (findOne) return an active record?

Comment: Yeah both are returning a record if i remove the name from within the request post the user model is updated but not the userprofile model unless i manually do it by doing $profile->bio = "test"; for example

Comment: Could you post the full code of the action in the controller?

Comment: The image is saved in the avatar directory?

Comment: Yeah the image saves but only if i remove the if statement around it as I cannot use the $profile due to the request post not working for the profile none of the other fields save though.